# Optional param in a JPQL Query causing issues with Instant Class

Tags: java, spring-data, eclipselink

I need to create a query capable to be executed even if you send a null values in its params, the params are Instant with default format ISO-8601, the query works without any param, but if I send the param it stops working. Any suggestions?

**CODE:**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT re " 
        + "FROM report re "
        + "WHERE ( "
        + "( re.date BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo) OR (:dateFrom IS NULL OR :dateTo IS NULL))"
List<Report> reportByDate(@Param("dateFrom") Instant dateFrom,
        @Param("dateTo") Instant dateTo)
```

**Error:**

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 
>   Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT DISTINCT T1.COL_1, T1.COL_2, T1.COL_3
>   FROM REPORT T1
>   WHERE ((T0.DATE BETWEEN TS '2000-03-07 17:01:01.0' AND TS '2030-03-07 17:01:01.0') OR ((2030-03-08T01[*]:01:01Z IS NULL) AND (2000-03-08T01:01:01Z IS NULL)))"; 
>   expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )"; SQL statement:

Comment: which database ?

Comment: H2 and Oracle DB